# differences between HDFS and ZooKeeper?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, bigdata

While reading ZooKeeper's documentation, it seems to me that HDFS relies on pretty much the same mechanisms of distribution/replication (broadly speeking) as ZooKeeper. I hear some echo from one to another, but I still can't distinguish things clearly and striclty.

I understand **ZooKeeper** is a Cluster Management / Sync tool, while **HDFS** is a Distributed File Management System, but could ZK be needed on an HDFS cluster for example?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the factor is distributed processing and high availability on a hadoop cluster with a zookeper's quorum

**For ex. Hadoop Namenode fail over process.**

Hadoop high availability is designed around Active Namenode & Standby Namenode for fail over process. At any point of time, you should not have two masters ( active Namenodes) at same time.

Zookeper resolves cluster address to an active namenode.